# Python Challenge

Tags: python, recursion

I am doing the coin-change problem. I have finished the problem, that it prints out how many coins I need to make the least amount of change possible, but how do I change my program so that it also prints those coins??

Here is a sample I/O:

```
input: coin_change(48, [1, 5, 10, 25, 50])

output: [6, [25, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1]]

input: coin_change(48, [1, 7, 24, 42])

output: [2, [24, 24]]
```

Currently my code only returns the 6.

By the way, this must be done with recursion only. No loops are allowed.

Code:

```
def change(C, V):
    def min_coins(i, aC):
        if aC == 0:
            return 0
        elif i == -1 or aC < 0:
            return float('inf')
        else:
            return min(min_coins(i-1, aC), 1 + min_coins(i, aC-V[i]))
    return min_coins(len(V)-1, C)
```

The code below is what I tried, but it does NOT work for the second input

```
def giveChange(C, V, res = None):
    res=[] if res is None else res
    if len(V)==0:
        return len(res),res
    maxx=max(V)
    print maxx
    V.remove(maxx)
    ans=C//maxx
    if ans==0 and maxx<C :
        print maxx
        res +=[maxx]*ans
        return  len(res),res
    else:
        res += [maxx]*ans
        return  giveChange(C % maxx,V,res)
```

Comment: Since this is homework (and even if it wasn't), we'd like to see some effort on your part, first. What have you tried? What worked? What hasn't? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Might not use maxx=max(V)

An optimal solution may comprise of small coins, for example 48=24+24, which has two coins, lesser than 48=25+10+10+1+1+1. In that case, though 25>24, you have to use more tiny coins to make a 48.

Thus if your input is (48, [1, 7, 24, 42]), you will be trapped in the second situation and get a 48 = 42+1+1+1+1+1+1. You can combine your second posted codes with your first one, add a list as parameter for storing the changes and use the same recursion design.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code will work with a few changes. Instead of returning just count, a function can return a list or even (count, [coins]) tuple. you may also want to sort V.

Comment: that is not important. my point is your first code is logically correct. With a few tweaks it will also return list of coins. it can be done without passing a mutable list as parameter.